# Where are commit messages stored in Atlassian Stash

Tags: git, sdk, bitbucket-server

I am trying to write a plugin for Atlassian Stash. I have downloaded the SDK, and I have access to the database we use for Stash, but I am unable to find a table that has a column for commit messages. I assume that they aren't deriving that from the hash or anything on the fly, but I have been completely unable to find them. What table are they stored in, or what method are they using to display them in the actual Stash application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the commit messages (as opposed to pull request descriptions) are not stored separately in Stash, they are retrieved from git as needed. The [Stash documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/stash/docs/latest/reference/java-api.html) lists the available Java APIs to access Git from within Stash plugins.

Comment: Ex-Stash developer here. That's correct - Stash doesn't "store" the commits (eg. in the DB), but just uses Git directly. You would need to use Git or the REST APIs to access them.

Comment: That's what I wound up doing. As a somewhat unrelated followup, is there a way to connect to the DB through the SDK, or do you just have to use ojdbc or something?

Comment: We don't tend to recommend direct DB access as it is an internal implementation details that is subject to change. If there's something you need that's not covered by a plugin SDK call or REST APIs, feel free to raise a suggestion at jira.atlassian.com.